# Conflicting JAX-RS versions for Jersey 2.23.1 with JAX-RS 2.0.1 on WebLogic 12.1.2 for javaee-web-api 6.0

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, weblogic, java-ee-6

I would like to use the latest Jersey libraries on WebLogic 12.1.2.
Out of the box, WLS supports an older jax-rs-2.0.war with Jersey 2.5.1, as a shared library.

My target is to deploy a newer Jersey version (e.g. 2.23.1).
However, I struggle with conflicting javax.ws.rs.core.* packages:

In the pox.xml, I have dependencies like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

javaee-web-api is referring to the Java EE 6 container of WLS 12c.
It contains some javax.ws.rs.* packages in a jax-rs 2.0.
Jersey however refers to jax-rs 2.0.1.

In weblogic.xml, I configured to use the application packages:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- apis -->
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.core.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.ws.rs.ext.*</package-name>
        ...
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Eclipse is fine with the setup and resolves JAX-RS 2.0.1.
However, maven build is looking at the javaee-web-api with JAX-RS 2.0 and gives compile errors.

How can I solve the maven build to consider the weblogic.xml, or drill down dependency evaluation of maven build at package level?